# What would be the best solution to making this animation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, android-animation

I am trying to make a game where you have multiple levels where you have to figure out a way to where a certain color should go through pipes that are displayed on the screen. The pipes look like [image: this] (it all should be better, but just as a reference). So basically there should be an animation of color going down these pipes (different color for different pipe). Now, I can make a gif and use that as my animation, but it's just too large (aprox. 5MB, which isn't a lot, but if you put dozens of levels, it tends to add up).What would be a solution that would be the most efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would first recommend you to go with Unity for Game Development.
If not then check out cocos2d or any other frameworks.
Secondly, if you want to animate things using the native code, then play around with `draw()` functions (as suggested by @Wakeman) of the Canvas.
Now coming to your question, if your game does not involve continuous user interaction and you are thinking of GIFs as a solution then I would recommend using **[Lottie library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)**.
You can create beautiful animations in Adobe After Effects and import those (json files) in Android without hurting much memory, plus would get high resolution output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the drawRect() or drawCircle()? You only need coordinations of the starting point, the turning points, and the ending point. Draw it with a recursive function with delay, and it should look good.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to construct your levels as tilemap. Every segment of pipe can be coded by number and drawn as bitmap (Sprite) that depends on its state (empty, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2 or full). Similar principles works for engines like Unity/Cocos 2D or your own renderer. This way of building your levels would be hundred times lighter in size than full screen animation and used multiple times for different levels.

[image: Tilemap example]